# How to regex between two square brackets with multiple lines? (grep|awk|python)

Tags: awk

I have this file with multiple json objects and am trying to grab the data in the array "ld" that continues to the next line. Is there a way to grab the first anchor '[' and the last anchor ']' as one set and then the next as another?

```
    {
        "test": 'asdfadfa',\n
        "happy": 'dq34werqedqe',\n
        "ld": [\n
            "creamer",\n
            "sugar",\n
            "honey"\n
        ]
    }
    {
        "test": 'asdfadfa',\n
        "happy": 'dq34werqedqe',\n
        "ld": [\n
            "coffee_creamer",\n
            "milk"
    ]\n
    }
.
.
.
```

Only want

```
"creamer", "sugar", "honey"
"coffee_creamer", "milk"
```

I have tried multiple was todo so even with [\r\n]+ but not able to match the first anchor is problem '[' to next anchor ']'.
I tried python but my file is to large to parse through and my memory keeps crashing it so figured to use regex with grep/awk.
Is it possible if not another way recommended would be amazing thanks.

Comment: and why exactly can't you use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) (or just a simple python dictionary) to get that data? also provide a [mre]

Comment: Dask dataframe is great tools for large dataset. It also can create dataframe  from set of JSON files. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_json.html

Comment: I used the json.dumps(file.read()) to a string but python couldn't store that much data  into a string. Was going to parse with regex but wasn,t able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is fragile and I do not recommend using it. There are tools available such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which are designed to handle json data, and would be more appropriate for this task (see e.g. https://cameronnokes.com/blog/working-with-json-in-bash-using-jq/ for more details).

Having said that, here is one potential method using awk:

If the "\n" characters are 'real':

```
awk '/"ld":/{flag=1; next} /]/{flag=0} flag' test.json
"creamer",
"sugar",
"honey"
"coffee_creamer",
"milk"

# Tidy up the output
awk '/"ld":/{flag=1; next} /]/{flag=0} flag' test.json | tr -s "\n" " " | sed 's/" "/"\n"/g; s/ //g'
"creamer","sugar","honey"
"coffee_creamer","milk"
```

If the "\n" characters are actually present, in addition to 'real' newlines:

```
awk '/"ld":/{flag=1; next} /]/{flag=0} flag' test.json | tr -s "\n" " " | sed 's/\\n//g; s/" "/"\n"/g; s/ //g'
"creamer","sugar","honey"
"coffee_creamer","milk"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you!! Can you explain the flag setting if possible for awk why flag=1 first and not 0?  Thanks again for cleaning up the output to with using sed and tr to make it look better!

Comment: Basically, at the first pattern match set flag=1 (marks the start point) and then at the next pattern match set flag=0 ('unset' the flag: marks the end point), and then when you print flag you get everything where flag=1 (the stuff between the start and end points). Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes and I can see how you set the /"ld":/ and the /]/ flags which made it parse through till the end flag was set off.